# signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT) relating to webview.apk

Tags: android, crash-reports, android-7.0-nougat, google-play-console

I'm receiving a handful of crash reports in my Play Console with the following title:

```
signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT)
webview.apk
```

and the following detail:

```
backtrace:
  native: pc 00000000011a1ed4  /system/app/webview/webview.apk
  native: pc 00000000011e01f8  /system/app/webview/webview.apk
```

That is it, no more information available.

What is significant is that (a) the number of crashes is very small, so my code must basically be sound, and (b) the reports are all from Android 7.0 devices.

How do I even begin to work out where the crash could be occuring?  I could post some code, but it probably won't help because the vast majority of devices aren't choking, and in any case I'm just looking for a bit of insight or hints as to where to look further.  I cannot reproduce this crash on any device I've tried.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38350812/4070848), also with no answer.

Comment: Do you use AdMob ads? https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/I6giN0VbVa0/discussion

Comment: @TalkLittle no :(

Comment: Same issue, did you find out what the problem is?

Comment: I guess not you did not...

Comment: No I did not :-(

Comment: Do you use ads? Do you use WebView for other purposes?

Comment: I also have thousand of these crashes after my last app update. I only use Admob ads and no webview (now Unified Native Advanced & Interstitial). I do not get these crashes in Firebase Crashlytics and it only affects Android v >= 7.x

Answer (score 5):

It's an known, un-fixable bug with the Chrome WebView on Android 7 and above. The WebView is used to display the ads whether you create one or not. It's not specific to AdMob. Don't count on this getting fixed, it's been present since 2017 and crashes are being forwarded to the Chrome team, not Admob team.

https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/google-admob-ads-sdk/3aa2ad26-f54c-46d1-9072-9c829297de9f%40googlegroups.com

Answer (score 1):

No fix found yet for this, in my app it happened when clicking a html5 date picker, I decided to avoid it using a normal textfield with mask https://vuejs-tips.github.io/vue-the-mask/